# Remove '' in query bindings in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, binding, single-quotes

I have this logic if the min and max is null change it to 'price'

```php
$post['min'] == NULL ? $post['min'] = 'price' : '';
$post['max'] == NULL ? $post['max'] = 'price' : '';
```

but when I have it in my query

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_name LIKE ? AND price BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY price ?";
$values = array(
    $this->security->xss_clean('%' . $post['item_name'] . '%'), 
    $this->security->xss_clean($post['min']), 
    $this->security->xss_clean($post['max']), 
    $this->security->xss_clean($post['order_by'])
);
$result = $this->db->query($query, $values)->result_array();
```

It throws a database error, says:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ASC'' at line 1
```

**How to remove the `''` in query bindings?**

Comment: what is `$post['order_by']` value? please `var_dump($values)`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not overly complex, so I might recommend using active record.  Use conditionally called `where()` methods to add filtering logic.

I have not tested the following suggestion and it assumes that all four elements exist in the `$post` array.

I don't think it makes sense to bloat your query with weird `price >= price` and `price <= price` logic -- just omit the column check if it is not valuable.

Recommended model method:

```
public function getItemsLikeBetween(array $post): array
{
    if (strlen($post['min'])) {
        $this->db->where('price >=', $post['min']);
    }
    if (strlen($post['max'])) {
        $this->db->where('price <=', $post['max']);
    }
    return $this->db
           ->like('item_name', $post['item_name'])
           ->order_by($post['order_by'])
           ->get('items')
           ->result_array();
}
```